# Upper Bound and Lower Bound of the Sum of the Prime Divisors of a Odd Semiprime

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-factorization, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum

Lets say we have $n$, an odd semiprime. $p$ and $q$ are odd primes, such that $pq=n$. What are the tightest upper and lower bounds of $p+q$ in terms of $n$ known right now? Right now, I have $2\sqrt n\leq p+q<n$ but I don't know if that's the tightest possible.

Comment: upper would be when $p=3$ and lower would be when $p=\sqrt n$

Comment: No, I meant what is the range of values $p+q$ can fall into.

Comment: Note:  $p+q=p+n/p$

Comment: Yes, but how is that any helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up the comments; without loss of generality $3\leq p\leq\sqrt{n}\leq q$, and because $n=pq$ we have
$$p+q=p+\tfrac np,$$
which is maximal when $p$ is minimal, and minimal when $p$ is maximal. Hence
$$2\sqrt{n}\leq p+q\leq 3+\tfrac n3.$$

Comment: Is this the tightest possible?

Comment: In what sense? For each semiprime $n$ the value of $p+q$ is uniquely determined, but my answer gives a range of values. For $n=9$ both inequalities are tight, though.

Comment: Also, why use $3$?

Comment: Because $p$ is an odd prime, so $p\geq3$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.